# 1987 dodge W100 making a loud tap/knock after rebuild

Tags: dodge, repair, ram, valve-lifter, connecting-rod

I have just finished rebuilding my 318 and have not even been able to move it yet, I started it and was hearing a very bad exhaust leak and tap. I put a left over gasket on the one side (along with the new one) and the sound from that side quieted .but the other side I didn’t have a gasket to put on and it is knocking very bad especially after removing the valve cover, is it a lifter or rod knock * note I put all new pistons but used the old connecting rods,but new bearings of course, it has hydraulic lifters that I thought may be collapsed, but it’s making a very deep noise, but the engine itself has a very deep tone

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! An exhaust leak at the header/head interface can sound a LOT like a rod knock. Get a new gasket on there and then see if the noise changes. Also, how is your oil pressure?

Comment: Please edit your question to add appropriate punctuation, dividing the wall of text into sentences. It's very hard to read this way.